# Delete Openvpn completely

Tags: linux, sys, openvpn, cgroups

By mistake I installed both server side and client side of Open-vpn and now I want to delete everything related to openvpn-server/client in my pc.
I already did.

```
$ sudo apt remove openvpn
$ sudo apt purge openvpn
$ sudo apt autoremove openvpn
```

But there are still these many files remaining.

```
$ sudo find / -type d -name "openvpn*" 2>/dev/null/

sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service
/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service
/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service
```

one thing to note is that these files do not show when I do `locate openvpn` after `sudo updatedb`. Then to remove them I tried to do.

```
$ sudo rm -rf $(sudo find / -type d -name "openvpn*" 2>/dev/null/)
$ sudo rm -r $(sudo find / -type d -name "openvpn*" 2>/dev/null/)
$ sudo rm -f $(sudo find / -type d -name "openvpn*" 2>/dev/null/)
```

But files still remain and this is the message they gave out.

```
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/devices.deny': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/devices.list': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/devices.allow': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/tasks': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/notify_on_release': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.clone_children': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.use_hierarchy': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.tcp.usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.soft_limit_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.force_empty': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.pressure_level': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.move_charge_at_immigrate': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.memsw.failcnt': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.tcp.max_usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.max_usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.oom_control': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.slabinfo': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.limit_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.swappiness': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.memsw.max_usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.numa_stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.failcnt': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.max_usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/tasks': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.failcnt': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.event_control': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.tcp.failcnt': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/notify_on_release': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.kmem.tcp.limit_in_bytes': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.clone_children': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/pids.current': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/pids.events': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/tasks': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/notify_on_release': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/pids.max': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.clone_children': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/tasks': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/notify_on_release': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.clone_children': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/tasks': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/notify_on_release': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.clone_children': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.events': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/io.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.max.descendants': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cpu.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/memory.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cpu.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.type': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.threads': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.freeze': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.controllers': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.subtree_control': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/system-openvpn\x2dserver.slice/openvpn-server@server.service/cgroup.max.depth': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.events': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/io.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.max.descendants': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cpu.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/memory.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cpu.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.type': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.threads': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.freeze': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.controllers': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.subtree_control': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/openvpn-iptables.service/cgroup.max.depth': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Well, just reboot. Research what is cgroup and how to remote cgroup groups.

Comment: @KamilCuk First Thankx 4 replying. But I have a question that is why do these file do not show up when I use `locate openvpn`, I also did `sudo updatedb` before locate to update the data base but they still did not show up.

Comment: `use locate openvpn` Because `sysfs` filesystem is excluded from scanning by `updatedb`. Check your `/etc/updatedb.conf` and research `sysfs` and `man updatedb.conf`. It sounds extremely odd if `mlocate` would index pseudofilesystems, but maybe there are use cases.